# Powershell Sharepoint Plugin not working

Tags: .net, powershell, sharepoint

I have a problem with the powershell SP plugin.

First I ran:

> Get-PSSnapin

to make sure it was not loaded yet. So then I ran:

> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

This gave me the following error:

> Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin],
>   PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

So then I mainly found the solution to run:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil
>   /LogToConsole=true
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll

This in turn gives me error:

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ShareP
>   oint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot fi nd the file
>   specified..

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong or provide me with a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have sharepoint installed on this machine?

Comment: Hello Alex, you are right, something was wrong with the sharepoint installation. Im going to reinstall and then it should work I guess. thank you.

Comment: Reinstallling SharePoint is... not pleasuring. I tried it once and it was just not possible. I would reinstall the whole Windows.

Comment: Ah ok, well I may have acces to another system :) But thnx for the heads up!